# configuring a dynamic websocket endpoint in azure apim

Tags: azure, websocket, policy, apim

I am trying to configure a azure apim websocket endpoint .

Below are the steps I tried

1. created a websocket endpoint
2. configured the settings as below
   `websocket url : wss://app.square.ai:5001/CustomerActionHub/51 Url suffix : exam/CustomerActionHub/51`

The above steps are working fine when I create it as static.

Now I have to configure in such a way where the above value 51 will change dynamically. How do I achieve that

below is the setting i tried but its throwing error

[image: steps tried in apim]

Comment: You can add it like `wss://app.square.ai:5001/CustomerActionHub/{}` and pass the value while sending request

Comment: I tried that it is giving the below error 

One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Invalid value of the Web API URL suffix

Comment: Can you share the screenshot please

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin - done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I have to configure in such a way where the above value 51 will change dynamically. How do I achieve that

You can use the below policy to accept the value as a query parameter while sending the request.

```xml
<inbound>
    <base  />
    <set-backend-service  base-url="@{ return "wss://app.square.ai:5001/CustomerActionHub/"+context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("CustomerId");}"  />
</inbound>
```

You can also use `rewrite-uri` but in case of WebSocket APIs, its not giving expected result. AFAIK, it might be because WebSocket APIs in Azure APIM is currently in public preview as per this [MS Docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-support-for-websocket-apis-in-azure-api-management-selfhosted-gateway/).

In my case I have used above policy to establish a connection with Azure PubSub Service and I am sending Hub Name in query parameter as shown below.

[image]

[image]

As a workaround, you can use the above given policy and meanwhile you can also check with the Product team for any further details.

Comment: So how do i give the websocket url and api url suffix in settings page ? Kindly guide

Comment: @Sindhu1990 After adding API, you just need to add this policy

Comment: @Sindhu1990 Hope this works for you

Comment: Yes thanks , sorry for the late acknowledgement